# Plotting Intensity Distribution of Laguerre Gaussian Function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I want to plot intensity of Laguerre Gaussian wave, My code is running accurately with changing `p(0,1,2...)` and `l=0` but when i want to plot with changing `l(0,1,2...)` and `p(0,1,2...)` it gives no output. How to plot it for `l=0,1,2` and `p=0,1,2`?

```
LG[r_, ϕ_, p_, l_, w_] :=Sqrt[(2 p!)/(π (p + Abs[l])!)] (1/w) *
  Exp[-r^2/w^2] ((r Sqrt[2])/w)^Abs[l]*
   LaguerreL[p, Abs[l], (2 r^2)/w^2] Exp[I l ϕ]

t11 =ContourPlot@[
  LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], 0, 0, 1]^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 
   4}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: just remove the @ and it works

Comment: and note that with your definition for l≠0 LG is complex. This works for instance `t11 = Table[
  ContourPlot[
   LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], p, l, 1]^2 // Abs, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], {l, 0, 2}, {p, 0, 2}]`

Comment: Respected chris, Thanks for answering, on plotting a white line appears in the contour plots for all varying l=0,1, 2 how can we remove this?

Comment: try `ContourPlot[
 LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], 2, 2, 1]^2 // Abs, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Exclusions -> None]`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Table[
   ContourPlot[
    LG[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], p, l, 1]^2 // Abs, {x, -3, 
     3}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 50, 
    Exclusions -> None, FrameTicks -> None], {l, 0, 2}, {p, 0, 2}] // 
  GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Note that I remove the `@` and added `// Abs`
because your definition of `LG` is complex for non zero `l`.

Comment: Now it is working well. Again Thank you very much Chris

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, unless you are waiting for another you could consider accepting this one?